# negative and or

Tags: negation, negative-polarity-items

With following two conditions,

- Do not use A, if possible.
- Do not use B, if possible.

How can I make it as a sentence? Which one is right?

- Do not use A or B, if possible.

or

- Do not use A nor b, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences are correct. See [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nor) for some examples that use *nor*. *Nor* sounds more formal and does not typically appear in colloquial English.

*Nor* is used to continue a negative phrase. In modern usage, *nor* usually appears after *neither*. For example,

> Use neither A nor B, if possible.

However, this example sacrifices the clearly imperative "Do not" at the beginning of the sentence. If I wanted clear and concise English, such as for "how to" instructions, I would probably use this:

> Do not use either A or B, if possible.

The *either* emphasizes that both options A and B are to be avoided.